# Azure Active Directory - Cross-tenant synchronization solution

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have a cu they have two tenant like Azure Global and Azure China, and they have a one on-prem AD, they want synchronization the on-prem AD to both Azure Global and Azure China, I have found the internal KB explain this solution but used the ADFS, the cu will be change the ADFS to the password hash synchronization.

Is this solution is supported and can be implement?

And any advice for this?

Thank you.
[solution arch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8sz9.png)

Comment: I think you'd have to implement the sync yourself..